# problem compiling libjingle

Tags: python, google-code, libjingle

I downloaded and installed libjingle-0.5.2.zip, and according to the README also downloaded and installed swtoolkit.0.9.1.zip, scons-local-2.1.0.alpha.20101125.tar.gz, and expat-2.0.1.tar.gz, and got nrtp by cvs download. After overwriting my Makefile twice, attempting to follow the rather poorly-written README, I came up with the following Makefile that almost works:

```
# First, make sure the SCONS_DIR environment variable is set correctly.
SCONS_DIR ?= /usr/src/scons-local/scons-local-2.1.0.alpha.20101125/
#SCONS_DIR ?= /usr/src/scons-local/
export
default: build
# Second, run talk/third_party/expat-2.0.1/configure...
talk/third_party/expat-2.0.1/Makefile:
    cd talk/third_party/expat-2.0.1 && ./configure
# ...and talk/third_party/srtp/configure.
talk/third_party/srtp/Makefile:
    cd talk/third_party/srtp && ./configure
# Third, go to the talk/ directory and run $path_to_swtoolkit/hammer.sh. Run
# $path_to_swtoolkit/hammer.sh --help for information on how to build for
# different modes.
build: talk/third_party/expat-2.0.1/Makefile talk/third_party/srtp/Makefile
    cd talk && ../../swtoolkit/hammer.sh
help:
    ../swtoolkit/hammer.sh --help
```

However, `make` gives me the following errors:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/usr/src/libjingle-0.5.2$ make
cd talk && ../../swtoolkit/hammer.sh
*** Error loading site_init file './../../swtoolkit/site_scons/site_init.py':
AttributeError: 'Dir' object has no attribute 'endswith':
  File "/usr/src/scons-local/scons-local-2.1.0.alpha.20101125/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1338:
    _exec_main(parser, values)
  File "/usr/src/scons-local/scons-local-2.1.0.alpha.20101125/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 1302:
    _main(parser)
  File "/usr/src/scons-local/scons-local-2.1.0.alpha.20101125/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 929:
    _load_site_scons_dir(d.path, options.site_dir)
  File "/usr/src/scons-local/scons-local-2.1.0.alpha.20101125/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 719:
    exec fp in site_m
  File "./../../swtoolkit/site_scons/site_init.py", line 455:
    SiteInitMain()
  File "./../../swtoolkit/site_scons/site_init.py", line 451:
    SCons.Node.FS.get_default_fs().SConstruct_dir, None)
  File "/usr/src/scons-local/scons-local-2.1.0.alpha.20101125/SCons/Script/Main.py", line 677:
    site_dir = os.path.join(topdir, site_dir_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 67:
    elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

I'm guessing that something new (a 'Dir' object being where a POSIX path string is expected) in one of the packages is breaking the build process, but which one? There are just too many layers of cruft here for me to follow. For sure I could just keep trying older packages, particularly for swtoolkit and scons, but if anyone here has successfully compiled libjingle and could prod me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: You'd be much better off asking the upstream developers about compilation problems.

Comment: probably. I posted this to the google voice forum and it disappeared. I'll try again.

Comment: it reappeared. judging by the first response, though, I'm not too optimistic of getting any help on that forum: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=0d405ecfebf33dc4&hl=en&fid=0d405ecfebf33dc400049e004bb0c834

Comment: I fighted with libjingle when it was in version 0.4. Seems nothing changed... I finally decided to use farsight, a gstreamer wrapper for libjingle. It was much easier to use.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the project, but think I have a fix to get you past that point.  You need to cast those `Dir` instances using `str()` in swtoolkit/site_scons/site_init.py. That way they can safely be evaluated by `path.endswith('/')`.  Odd that such an issue would exist for very long in the main part of the build infrastructure:

Line 330:

```
SCons.Script.Main._load_site_scons_dir(
    str(SCons.Node.FS.get_default_fs().SConstruct_dir), site_dir)
```

Line 450:

```
SCons.Script.Main._load_site_scons_dir(
    str(SCons.Node.FS.get_default_fs().SConstruct_dir), None)
```

Answer (score 3):

I did following to build libjingle :

### Building LibJingle for Linux

1. How to Build

Libjingle is built with swtoolkit ( http://code.google.com/p/swtoolkit/), which
is a set of extensions to the open-source SCons build tool ( http://www.scons.org).

- First, install Python 2.4 or later from http://www.python.org/.
  Please note that since swtoolkit only works with Python 2.x, you will
  not be able to use Python 3.x.
- Second, install the stand alone scons-local package 2.0.0 or later from
  http://www.scons.org/download.php and set an environment variable,
  `SCONS_DIR`, to point to the directory containing SCons, for example,
  `/src/libjingle/scons-local/scons-local-2.0.0.final.0/`.
- Third, install swtoolkit from http://code.google.com/p/swtoolkit/.
- Finally, Libjingle depends on two open-source projects, expat and srtp.
  Download expat from http://sourceforge.net/projects/expat/ to
  talk/third_party/expat-2.0.1/. Follow the instructions at
  http://sourceforge.net/projects/srtp/develop to download latest srtp to
  talk/third_party/srtp. Note that `srtp-1.4.4` does not work since it misses
  the extensions used by Libjingle.
  If you put expat or srtp in a different directory, you need to edit
  `talk/libjingle.scons` correspondingly.

2.1 Build Libjingle under Linux or OS X

- First, make sure the `SCONS_DIR` environment variable is set correctly.
- Second, run `talk/third_party/expat-2.0.1/configure` and
  `talk/third_party/srtp/configure`.
- Third, go to the talk/ directory and run `$path_to_swtoolkit/hammer.sh`. Run
  `$path_to_swtoolkit/hammer.sh --help` for information on how to build for
  different modes.

## Other than above given steps, See following as reference

#### Set SCONS_DIR Path

```
export SCONS_DIR=/home/esumit/libjingle/libjingle-0.5.2/talk/third_party/scons-local/scons-local-2.0.1
```

Install `libasound2-dev` Lib to compile libJingle, otherwise you will encounter errors.

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

Download SRTP using the following command. If it asks for a passowrd, just hit Enter.

```
cvs -z3 -d:pserver:anonymous@srtp.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/srtp co -P srtp
```

#### Possible components in LibJingle Directory

```
libjingle-0.5.2/talk/third_party$ ls
expat-2.0.1  libudev  scons-local  srtp  swtoolkit
```

#### Execute following command to build LibJingle

```
libjingle-0.5.2/talk$ ./third_party/swtoolkit/hammer.sh
```

Comment: +1 thank you Sumit. I'm glad it works "out of the box" now, it didn't back when I posted the question.