# Link error when build libjingle on Mac OS X 10.7.2

Tags: macos, linker-errors, rpath, libjingle

I want to build libjingle on Mac OS X 10.7.2. I just overcome the compiler error and meet the linker error now. The path `/Developer/libjingle/libjingle-0.6.3/talk/build/dbg/lib` exists but system says unknown. How can I fix it and make libjingle really work?

```
MBP17:talk rei25$ /Developer/swtoolkit/hammer.sh
scons: Reading SConscript files ...

scons: warning: The build_dir keyword has been deprecated; use the variant_dir keyword instead.
File "/Developer/swtoolkit/site_scons/site_init.py", line 203, in BuildEnvironmentSConscripts
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
scons: `all_libraries' is up to date.
________Linking build/dbg/obj/login
ld: unknown option: -rpath=/Developer/libjingle/libjingle-0.6.3/talk/build/dbg/lib
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [build/dbg/obj/login] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Answer (score 0):

The patch I posted to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036592/error-at-building-libjingle-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2-like-error-string-h-no-such-fi) fixes this issue as well. In the SCons build file for libjingle they remove the default RPATH for the linux build. I don't know SCons at all, so I'm not sure how it gets in there to begin with. I noticed the linux build removes the default, so I removed it for the OS X build, this appears to work. Although ld for OS X is suppose to take a rpath parameter, I believe it's not suppose to have an equal sign between rpath and the actual path. So thats why it may be failing, however you don't need to have it set at all.  But, I haven't run the unit tests yet to know if removing the rpath param will cause an runtime problem. Atleast it compiles now.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your main.scons as below:

```
# Remove default rpath set by Hammer. Hammer sets it to LIB_DIR, which is wrong.   
mac_env.Replace(
  RPATH = [],
)
```

Thanks.
Kane.

Comment: This was already present in my main.scons, still getting the same error.